# Проблемы с docker в Mint 20+

Tags: docker

При подобной ошибке:

```
Ошб:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu uma Release                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 55.55.555.55 443]
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово            
E: Репозиторий «https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu uma Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
```

Comment: не нужно в вопрос вслучать ответ, мы можете оформить это отдельно, отвечать на свои вопросы не запрещено

Answer (score -1):

для минт 19+

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
# Добавить строчку
# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
sudo apt update && sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

для минта 20 +

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

focal - берем версию под текущую.
https://linuxmint.com/download_all.php  - список версий минта.

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list | grep docker
```

должно быть

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

если нет - меняйте

Если у кого есть проблемы с минтом подобного типа отпишите ниже. Пригодится.